# Не работает конкатенация в BASH

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash

У меня на линуксе странно работатет конкатенацияю Запускаю такой код :

```sh
VAR1="Hello,"
VAR2=" World"
VAR3="$VAR1$VAR2"
echo "$VAR3"
```

Ожидаю результат Hello World !
Однако в консоли мне показываеться :

```
root@mystat:/bot# ./start.sh
 World
```

Что это может быть ? Вот `bash --version` :

```
bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.4.20(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Comment: Странно, у меня (`Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS`) все работает правильно. Попробуйте, `echo $VAR1` что выводит?

Comment: Hello, как и ожидалось

Comment: Тогда последовательно 1) `echo "$VAR1$VAR2"` что выводит?

Comment: World тоже самое что и в Var3

Comment: Странно. Попробуйте набрать в консоли (или просто скопируйте отсюда): `v1=a; v2=b; echo $v1$v2` Что получается?

Comment: `v1=a; v2=b; echo $v1$v2
ab` странно почему этот метод не работатет ?

Comment: OK. Если видите `ab`, значит где-то у себя ошиблись в наборе символов (mistype) / Наберите в консоли руками еще раз свой пример и если все будет как надо. скопируйте в скрипт

Comment: Да при вводе в конслось все заработало. Кстати я заметил что если поставить ; после 1 строки все выводиться нормально однако выдаёться ошибка типа команда не найдена.

Comment: Тут остается только *внимательно* посмотореть еще раз на свой текст скрипта. Где-то что-то не то набито

Comment: ОК еще раз проверю скрипт

Comment: Ставлю на то что в `VAR1=...` «А» — русская... ну или какой-то невидимый символ юникода закрался... в вопросе всё правильно, но подозреваю, что это было набрано заново, а не скопировано...

Answer (score 2):

Попробовал пример. Скопировал содержимое из вопроса в файлик.

```
$ ./t.sh
 World
```

то есть, как и у автора вопроса, не работает. Посмотрел, что внутри:

```
$ cat t.sh | xd
000000 56 41 52 31 3d 22 48 65 6c 6c 6f 2c 22 0d 0a 56  >VAR1="Hello,"..V<
                                              ^^ ^^
```

Никому эти два знака не показались подозрительными? Сохранил файл в unix формате и запустил снова:

```
$ ./t.sh
Hello, World
```